# Defining global accessors

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have two Python files:

"testclass.py":

```
class TestClass:
    Result = 0
    def __init__(self):
        self.Result = 1
        return
Manager = TestClass()
```

and "hostapp.py":

```
import testclass

print Manager.Result # should equal 1
```

I'd prefer to simply include the accessory class (testclass) in my main class, then use an accessor that's already been initialized, but when I run hostapp.py, I get the following error:

```
NameError: name 'Manager' is not defined
```

Would someone please explain to me why the "global" variable Manager (which should be an instance of TestClass) is only accessible from within the class? I know I can access it using:

```
testclass.Manager
```

but that's not how I planned to access it. Help?

Edit:

After making the change suggested by Martineau, the accessor works as intended:
    from testclass import Manager

Comment: Use `from testclass import Manager`.

Comment: or declare the instance in your second file, not in the class one .

Comment: As a side note: You're creating an old-style class; don't do that, use `class TestClass(object)`. You're also creating a class attribute, and then immediately hiding it with an instance attribute of the same name; don't do that either. You don't need `return` at the end of a function. Using the same naming style for types and values is confusing; even if you don't want to use PEP 8, use some style that makes it clear that `Manager` is not the same kind of thing as `TestClass`. Finally, "module" and "class" are very different things; you're confusing them.

Comment: Anyway, what's your actual question here? You know that `testclass.Manager` works, so presumably you understand that Python modules are namespaces and "global" means "module-global" not "everything-global". Are you asking how to trick Python into making "everything-global" variables? About why Python was designed this way? Something different?

Comment: @martineau has the answer I was looking for. Probably should have mentioned that I am new to Python...

Comment: @abarnet - I understand the differences between modules and classes, but being new to Python, may have inadvertently crosswired the two. What would you suggest? (I'm attempting to access the class TestClass solely through the static instance, "Manager".) I'm OK with any suggestions....